# Update my photo on Google Maps without re-uploading

Tags: google-maps, photos, photo-sharing

Is there any way to update my own photo on Google Maps without deleting it and uploading again?

For instance, I have some poorly merged panorama uploaded, which has already some views:

[image]

And I want to do some very simple fix like below along with keeping those views saved.

[image]

Of course, Google's policy might not allow changing the content of the photo, but I think such changes can be considered as enhancements (as well as small color correction, horizon fixing, lens distortions, etc.)

Comment: you should try to reach out to google via their feedback system

Comment: thank for suggestion, sent them a feedback

Answer (score 1):

You just can't. There is no such feature on Google Maps which would allow you to do so. Your only option is to send feedback and requesting such functionality or try to solve it with Google via their feedback system:

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you for advice, I have already requested it via their feedback system.